# Class 'Foo' incorrectly extends base class 'Baz' with private keyword

Tags: typescript

I got a typing error that says:

```
Class 'Foo' incorrectly extends base class 'Baz'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'bar'.(2415)
```

```
class Bar {}

class Baz {
  constructor(private bar: Bar) {}
}

class Foo extends Baz {
  constructor(private bar: Bar) {
    super(bar);
  }
}
```

When I change `private` to `public` it's okay, but why? Why can't I use `private`? Is there a way to use `private`? Is `public` a good alternative to `private`?

Comment: "*When I change private to public it's okay. but why?*" because subclasses are allowed to have the same private properties as a superclass. "*public is good alternative to private?*" do you want your property to be publically accessible or not? And if you want it only visible within the hierarchy but not from outside, why not `protected`? What is the overall goal here?

Comment: Just don't redeclare the property in the child, it can still be a constructor parameter: https://tsplay.dev/mZroJm. For the rest of your question I agree with the comment above, what's a _"good alternative"_ depends entirely on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's start by typing the "extended" version of what you wrote:

```
class Bar {}

class Baz {
    private bar: Bar;

    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Foo extends Baz {
    private bar: Bar;

    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        super(bar);
    }
}
```

As you can see you're defining a private attribute with the same name in both your parent and child class. What you want to do is probably this:

```
class Bar {}

class Baz {
    protected bar: Bar;

    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Foo extends Baz {
    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        super(bar);
    }
}
```

That using the "short" version became:

```
class Bar {}

class Baz {
    constructor(protected bar: Bar) {}
}

class Foo extends Baz {
    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        super(bar);
    }
}
```